# VSCODE Vertical left side bar hidden

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I searched for this a lot and coudn't find an answer. I must have pressed a shortcut because all of the sudden the left vertical menu bar was removed. For reference look in the before and after pictures.[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

As you could see the bar beside the explorer to the left is gone... How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

View->Appearance->Activity Bar

[image]